# Which is correct: "...despite you're not wanting..." or "...despite your not wanting...?"

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct: "...despite you're not wanting..." or "...despite your not wanting...?"

I read a post where the writer said he didn't want to get anyone's hopes up and I wanted to reply that he had. I'm not sure whether to use the possessive "your" because it's his thought that I'm referring to, or the contraction "you're" because it's a verb. I think "your" is correct in this example but I'm not at all sure.

Comment: I'm a first time poster and I guess I offended some people on this site. I apologize. I didn't realize my question was "off-topic." Please withdraw the question. Thank you to Damian for responding anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the context, if it's a possessive thing I would use your.
e.g : despite your not wanting to do have this; I gave it to you anyway
If it's anything other than that I would use you're

Comment: Please remove, or I'll return to downvote. 'Despite you're not wanting ...' is ungrammatical.

Comment: Edwin, I don't know if your comment is directed at Damian or me (Frank), but I've asked the moderator to withdraw my question. Sorry to have upset you with my ignorance of the rules of your site. Be well.

Comment: Wow we have the same surname! This is the first time I've seen someone with the same surname as me.